# Laravel using Carbon::today how to get date value from a datetime field?

Tags: php, laravel, date, datetime

Here is my controller code. How can I get date value from a datetime field?

```
public function UserContentShowDateList(){
'usercontents'=>UserContent::where('status',1 )->where('date', Carbon::today())->get()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UserContent::where('status',1 )->where(DB::raw('DATE(date)'), Carbon::today())->get();
```

I think this will help to get the Date only from datetime field.

Answer (score 0):

You can use whereDate

```
UserContent::where('status',1 )->whereDate('date', today())->get();
```

Add date field to the $dates prop inside your model.

```
protected $dates = ['date'];
```